# GET Tags on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I'm working on a script that requires I get a variable so we goto the right location on the site.

I want to do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dir/script.js?x=103"></script>
```

But how would I get that?

Comment: this might help http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri-split-url.

Comment: I don't get your question. Does @Kolink answer you correctly? I'm just not sure.

Comment: Sort of; It works somewhat and is manageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the filename of the script within the script itself, search all `<script>` tags for the one that contains the relevant filename in its `src` attribute. Then `split` it on `?` and read the value.